# How does Hulu know my local time when I am behind a VPN?

Tags: vpn, geolocation

To see what would happen, I attempted to access Hulu from a VPN outside the US. As I expected, Hulu detected the VPN. My understanding is that this is because Hulu is aware of the IP address ranges that belong to known VPNs. However, what caught me by surprise was Hulu's ability to display the time of the incident **in my local time zone**. How can this be possible? How does Hulu know in which time zone I am actually located?

Comment: javascript maybe or DNS leaks

Comment: Simple Javascript - which is running locally in your browser. See also [How to get the exact local time of client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659523/how-to-get-the-exact-local-time-of-client).

Comment: Can you elaborate? My browser does not have access to my location services (running Chrome on macOS), so I don't see how javascript would do it. How would DNS leaks cause it either? I have my machine set to use google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ah i see, I was making a bigger assumption. So what you're saying is just that the javascript relies on simple client side APIs to print a timestamp in my local time zone, Hulu is not actually able to detect where I am?

Comment: @saltthehash: I'm not saying that Hulu is not able to detect where you are. I'm only saying that such detection is not necessary to show the local time (or at least what is considered local by the settings of the computer) in the users browser. You can try to change the time zone in your computer without actually moving to another time zone and then check what gets displayed by Hulu.

Comment: Change the time zone on your computer and see if it changes.

Comment: Javascript can print the timestamp to a string and then send the string to the server, so hulu can know,  or javascript might just be used client-side to write the timestamps as local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By asking your browser for the current time zone offset, e.g.

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getTimezoneOffset())
```

Since I'm in the US/Pacific time zone and it's currently summertime, this returns 420 (7 x 60) for me.

[With a bit of additional clever code](https://github.com/iansinnott/jstz), it's possible to estimate the exact time zone, rather than just the current offset.